# Where can I find the 'Profiles' folder of GTA V?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I want to install a save game, but I cant find the 'Profiles' folder.

I looked in `\Documents\GTA V` but there are only two folders there: 'User music' and 'Settings'. I can't find the 'Profiles' folder, where I should put my save file. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

I found it at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Socialclub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V
```

Enter that in the path when normally pasting a location for a file in Finder.

Answer (score 1):

The only working way is the way I am going to tell you. Mine was not in any "Social Club" location. I found it this way:

1. Download ["Quick Search" by Glarysoft](https://www.glarysoft.com/quick-search/).
2. Use the program to search for "SGTA".
3. You should see the path for your saved game.

Mine was at this path:

C:\Users\Mistake\AppData\Roaming\Goldberg SocialClub Emu Saves\GTA V\0F74F4C4

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! I can see how you came to your solution, but there are two elements in it that are problematic.

Comment: 1 - You are telling us to download "Quick Search". I can see why you would suggest it - this allows quicker searching of the files. However, it is in no way required; all it does is perform the same search functions built in to the Windows operating system, only quicker. The idea of searching has also already been covered by another answer; you *could* suggest we use this program to make the process easier, but you would need to provide more information.

Comment: 2 - The folder you provide is deceptive. That is not the folder GTAV normally saves in. You appear to be using the Goldberg emulator, which is a Steam emulator primarily used to permit online multiplayer functionality over LAN. I am not familiar with the legality of this emulator, but if it is fine it might be useful to advise users that using this emulator may give them a similar path; but most GTAV players will have a completely different path, as described in most of the other answers.

Comment: Hey i just said download quick search because searching with windows's search takes a year for me to find it (not mentioned that 20% times it does not find the file while i already found the file with exact same name!).. Just search whatever way you want.

Comment: 2 - i don't know what is goldberg emulator.. i just downloaded gta v repack from somewhere and i found out i can't employ 100% saves on it. after a week searching with no result, i decided to find a way on my own. i do not force anyone to install the software. i just immediately announced the exact way that i did and it was successful. As anyone sees it is only a search software, so you can first try another search options.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to type SocialClub into the search in C Drive location and it will find out where it's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The Profiles folder is located in `<Documents>\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles` (most people say that is in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V\Profiles`, but Windows allows users to change the location of the Documents folder so this is not always true).

To install a save, you can drop it into one of the folders inside of Profiles with alphanumeric characters like "38AC7DF1". If you have more than one, try to guess which one it is based on the number of existing saves and timestamps.

If you don't have a Profiles folder in `<Documents>\Rockstar Games\GTA V`, you are probably running a pirate copy. All of the versions of GTA V (R* Warehouse, RGL, Steam and EGS) create the Profiles folder to store saved data.